# Groovy: writing dynamically compiled class to disc

Tags: groovy, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

In my app I need to compile classes / scripts in runtime.

as a `Class`:

```
Class<? extends LoginAdapter> clazz = groovyClassLoader.loadClass name
LoginAdapter la = clazz.newInstance id, logo
```

or as a `Closure`:

```
Closure action = groovyShell.evaluate( script, name ) as Closure
```

Both ways work like charm.

Now I need to be able to write the compiled classes/scripts to some persistant storage (disc) and later restore them back without compiling from scratch.

How can this be done?

Comment: Serializable should help. However from your examples not clear what you want to store: class or instance. How you want to reuse stored object?

Comment: @daggett I want to store the class. The 2nd example can also be re-arranged into a class.

Comment: Theoretically you could extend GroovyClassLoader and override createCollector that is used to collect inmemory compiled classes from one source. There is also CompilationUnit available in this method that is actually do compilation and has getClasses() method that returns GroovyClass list that has getBytes() method... But as for me it's easier to use groovyc to run compilation.

Comment: @daggett thanks for the hints! can `groovyc` be run programmatically?

Comment: groovyc starts `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler`. check it.

Comment: @daggett I ended up using `new org.codehaus.groovy.tools.Compiler( cc ).compile 'som.pck.SomeClass', body`. Thanks for the hints. Feel free to write down the answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be interested, this is my programming kata:

```
class Base {
  String answer() { null }
  String question() { 'WHAT IS.... ?' }
}
```

```
class ClazzSpec extends Specification {

  def "test compile"() {
    given:
    String packageName = 'some.pckg'
    String body = """
package $packageName

class SomeClass extends Base {
  Closure cl = { a -> println a }
  @Override String answer(){ '42' }
  String json( m ){ JsonOutput.toJson( m ) }
  String longOne( int times ){ 
    times.times{ sleep 100 }
    'done'
  }
}
"""

    CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration( targetDirectory:new File( './out' ) )
    ImportCustomizer imp = new ImportCustomizer()
    imp.addStarImports 'groovy.json', Base.package.name
    cc.addCompilationCustomizers imp, new ASTTransformationCustomizer( value:1, TimedInterrupt )

    new Compiler( cc ).compile packageName + '.SomeClass', body

    File base = new File( './out' )

    GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader()
    gcl.addClasspath './out'
    Class clazz = gcl.loadClass 'some.pckg.SomeClass'

    when:
    def inst = clazz.newInstance()

    then:
    inst.question() == 'WHAT IS.... ?'
    inst.answer() == '42'
    inst.json( [ q:42 ] ) == '{"q":42}'
    inst.longOne( 2 ) == 'done'

    when:
    inst.longOne 11

    then:
    thrown TimeoutException
  }

}
```